# How to verify that my Google Analytics filter is working?

Tags: google-analytics

Please don't kill me if I'm asking this question in the wrong place.

I have followed these [instructions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034823?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=1032939) to exclude myself from Google Analytics. How can I verify that my filter is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would say to checkout Real-time reports, but they don't apply filters and will show you all traffic.

One way I check to see if they are working (and I am assuming you've applied a IP filter), is to create two Views (profiles), one that includes only your IP and one that excludes your IP. Then, go visit a bunch of pages on your site and wait a few hours (2-3 usually) and you should start seeing data in the internal only profile, and not seeing data in the external profile.

There could be another way, but this has worked for me.

Comment: Actually real time reports started to support filters a few months ago, so by now this would be indeed the way to check.

Comment: I stand corrected, Eike is correct, you can check via real-time reports. Missed the memo on that one. Thanks Eike

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll trust you are right so have accepted your answer but I cannot get my brain around the Google Analytics Admin pages. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Why does it take 2-3 hours for data to be displayed? Not exactly "real time"

Comment: "Changes made to views may take up to two hours to reflect in Real-Time." - hope this helps someone. If you added an IP filter leave it a few hours before testing that it worked. Read more: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1638635?hl=en